# Grub : linux command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-12.10

I'm having an issue and I hope someone can help me,

I installed ubuntu 12.10 on my computer (along side windows 7) from a live cd, but when I rebooted my computer after a succefull installation, I get grub prompt, when I type boot in it, it prints "*Error 8: Kernel must be loaded before booting*".

So I searched and I found this link : [Loading Ubuntu From Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21342/how-can-i-load-ubuntu-when-all-i-have-is-grub), but when I type `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5` I get this message "*Warning! No such command: linux*"

Does anybody have any idea about what I should do ?

Note that I reinstalled ubuntu but still get the same issue, and that this is not my first time installing ubuntu (I installed a lot of versions a dozen of times before and this is the first time I face this issue).

**Edit :**

When I type : `kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5` instead of : `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5` I get *Error 15: File not found* (I also tried sda4 since `find /vmlinuz` is printing `hd(0,4)`)

Comment: Do you have any access to a shell? If so, try to locate the grub using this simple command -> <whereis grub> The command should return something like this -> grub: /usr/sbin/grub /etc/grub.conf /usr/lib/grub /usr/share/man/man8/grub.8.gz  Then try to read your grub.conf file, perhaps you can solve the problem with this file.. If possible post your grub.conf file here..

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used the live cd to access a terminal and mounted the /dev/sda5 where my installation is, the command gave me this output : `grub : /etc/grub.d /usr/lib/grub /usr/share/grub` (I think these are the grub files for the live cd no ?), I executed I searched for **grub.conf** using find but I could not find it.

Comment: Try to use the information in this address -> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Manually_creating_grub.cfg

Answer (score 1):

SCSI disk partitions numbering starts from 1, grub partition numbering starts from 0, therefore `/dev/sda5` and `hd(0,4)` are the same.

What you wanted to say in the grub shell is

```
root (hd0,4)
kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5
initrd /initrd 
boot
```

It is likely that your Ubuntu installation did not complete. You may want to reinstall.

Comment: I did reinstall it but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Well, another alternative might be to re-install grub. Boot using a live disk and open a terminal.

```
$sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt #x is the partition in which you have intalled ubuntu
$chroot /mnt
$grub-install --boot-directory=DIR /dev/sda  

#DIR is the directory where your boot/grub2 folder is in my case it is /dev/sda6/boot/grub2 . In your case it must be a different sdx. You have to figure it out.

$update-grub2
```

Comment: There is no `grub2-install` command, there is `grub-install`, I tried executing it and it gives me : "**Path '/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting**"

Comment: I'm sorry grub2-install is in fedora. In ubuntu it is just grub-install. The error that you are reporting arises when your boot folder is in different partition than the one in which your / is . This is the same reason as to why you are unable to boot from grub rescue. It is possible, but it is a bit tricky. For my method, you can see my updated post.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the output of the command sudo fdisk -l

Comment: Did you use these set of commands? (i)set root=(hd0,4) (ii)linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda4 (iii)initrd /initrd.img (iv)boot

Comment: I did try those commands (see my edit in my question), as for your previous comment, I will try that asap and tell you what I get. thank you for your help